# Ejecutar un archivo cron cada x tiempo que se indique usando la librería Crontab de python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, crontab, cronjobs

Estoy intentando desarrollar un programa que realice una sincronización con un servidor web cada cierto tiempo, para ello estoy usando Crontab, el problema es que para indicar que se ejecute por ejemplo cada 2 minutos y 4 días pues me da error. Os muestro lo que hago:

```
def anhadir_sincronizacion(ruta, token, ServidorWeb, min, horas, dias, meses):
""" Function para añadir una sincronizacion a partir de la ruta del archivo,token y url del Servidor cada x tiempo. """
usuario = getuser()
wd = os.getcwd()
wd = ' python3 ' + wd + '/sincronizacion.py' + ' ' + ruta + ' ' + token + ' ' + ServidorWeb
print(wd)
my_cron = CronTab(user=usuario)
job = my_cron.new(command=wd, comment=ruta)
if meses != 0:
    job.month.every(meses)
    job.day.every(dias)
    job.hour.every(horas)
    job.minute.every(min)
elif meses == 0 and dias != 1:
    job.day.every(dias)
    job.hour.every(horas)
    job.minute.every(min)
elif meses == 0 and dias == 1 and horas != 0:
    job.hour.every(horas)
    job.minute.every(min)
elif meses == 0 and dias == 1 and horas == 0 and min != 0:
    job.minute.every(min)

if job.is_valid():
    my_cron.write()
    return True
else:
    print("La sincronizacion no es correcta")
    return False
```

Tal como está funciona en muchos casos pero si llamo por ejemplo a `anhadir_sincronizacion(ruta,token ServidorWeb, 0,2,1,1)` me da el siguiente error:

```
OSError: Program Error: /usr/bin/crontab returned 1: b'"/tmp/tmpm1h9gszr":75: bad minute\nerrors in crontab file, can\'t install.\n'
```

He probado a llamar `job.hour.also.on(tiempo)` pero el problema que tengo con este es que me configura cron de manera que se ejecute la hora del día que se indica y yo lo quiero es que se ejecute cada cierta cantidad de tiempo.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: `min` es el nombre de una función. Renombra la variable como `minuto` e intenta de nuevo.

Comment: @CandidMoe ya he probado y nada .Estoy probando distintas formas de realizar con crontab pero ninguna satisface lo que quiero al 100%.Lo único que quiero es que se ejecute el archivo cada cierto tiempo, no el 2ª dia de x mes.

Comment: Ejecute tu código y no me marca error. Tampoco genera el job, pero ese ya sería otro problema.

Comment: Lo que corresponde es programar una ejecución y que, cuando se lance la siguiente, ese proceso valide alguna configuración que definas y fije el cron para que sea dentro de X tiempo. Eso o decirle `0/5` para que corra cada 5 minutos, horas, días, etc.

Comment: @Alfabravo hola tu respuesta es muy buena, solo hay un problema y es que el 0/5 no cumple con el estándar de cron, por lo que puede que no funcione en los cron que se cree, aun así gracias.

Comment: Ahí es donde te equivocas. `0/5` corre cada 5 de lo que sea que uno le diga, comenzando en 0. `0  1/5  0  ?  *  *  *` corre cada 5 minutos desde el minuto 1, en el segundo cero, hora cero, cada día,... Prueba [aquí](https://freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)